# How to draw lines on Y axis ? (C infography)

Tags: c, graphics, line

I would like to draw lines on Y axis (one x for several y) but I don't find the algorithm to do it.

My code only draws horizontal lines, but I can't draw vertical lines.
I tried to swap x1 with y1 and x2 with y2 but it did not work.

Here is the code :

```
int     ft_abs(int nb)
{
    if (nb < 0)
        return (nb *= -1);
    return (nb);
}

//lst is my coordinates list
//s_mlx is my graphical lib
void    ft_draw(t_fdf *lst, t_mlx *s_mlx)
{
    int x;

    while (lst->next)
    {
        if ((lst->x <= lst->next->x) && (lst->next->x - lst->x >= ft_abs(lst->next->y - lst->y)))
        {
            x = lst->x;
            while (x <= lst->next->x)
            {
                mlx_pixel_put(s_mlx->mlx, s_mlx->win, x, lst->y + \
                        (lst->next->y - lst->y) * (x - lst->x) / \
                        (lst->next->x - lst->x), 0x00FFFFFF);
                x++;
            }
        }
        if ((lst->x <= lst->next->x) && (lst->next->x - lst->x <= ft_abs(lst->next->y - lst->y)))
        {
            x = lst->x;
            while (x <= lst->next->x)
            {
                mlx_pixel_put(s_mlx->mlx, s_mlx->win, x, lst->y + \
                        (lst->next->y - lst->y) * (x - lst->x) / \
                        (lst->next->x - lst->x), 0x00FFFFFF);
                x++;
            }
        }
        lst = lst->next;
    }
}
```

And here is the output (only horizontal lines) :

[image: image of Above code output]

How can I draw lines on `Y` axis (one x for several y)  to have a kind of grid ? (swapping `x1` with `y1`, and `x2` with `y2` did not work)

Comment: You have to give us more. What did not work? What have you tried explicitly?

Comment: C has no notion of "drawing" anything, although there may be libraries that can be used from C for doing so.  Thus, questions about how to draw anything would dependent on what such library you are using.

Comment: I think  he's using this: https://github.com/Katasa/Epitech1_RT-V1/tree/master/minilibx

Comment: @Martin, The function that I posted drew the image that I posted above. There are only horizontal lines, but I want to draw vertical lines too (from x0-y0 to x0-y1 ... x0-yMax and so on for each x) to have a sort of grid.

Comment: What I did to draw those vertical lines was to swap lst->x with lst->y and lst->next->x with lst->next->y but it did not work.

Comment: @Scott Hunter, I want to do this myself like I already did with horizontal lines, without using a fonction of my graphical library.

Comment: @MillieSmith you are right, I am using this library.